# Can we extend a parent class with constructor defined as internal and this class is in another namespace?

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance, constructor

I am developing a C# program and would like to extend a parent class with constructor marked as internal and this class is defined in another namespace in one of dll file?

Is there any way to make it work other than updating code of parent class?

Comment: It's a little unclear what you are asking. `internal` restricts access to other code in the same dll, not the same namespace.

Comment: look up `internal` meaning in C# on msdn.

Comment: No(I assume you mean different libraries).that is the objective of making the parent constructor internal,so no other library can access it. To achieve what you desired, you should have set it as protected internal .

Comment: Let me make it more clear. I am using one dll in which one class is defined with constructor marked as internal. Now in my project I am creating on class and extending the parent class from that dll. During this process I am getting error of parent class has no constructors defined.

Comment: @bravo - Right, the constructor isn't visible outside of the DLL it's defined in (because it's marked as internal.)

Comment: You might want to have a look at the [decorator design pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern). It might help.

Comment: @Nate222 - Is there any way to resolve this problem?

Comment: @bravo - If you have access to the DLL source code, you could mark the constructor as `protected internal` if that won't break any other code. Otherwise, you're stuck.

Comment: Okay @Nate222.. I got your point.. Thanks. :)

Thank to all.

Comment: If you mark it as `protected internal` you will not be able to overwrite as `internal` restrict the use usage to that assembly only. It has to be modified with `public` access modifier.